# trying to configure icinga2 directory for mail notifications for any type of alerts

Tags: icinga2

I have icingaweb2 web interface for icinga2 with director.

I would like to send email notifications for any type of alerts in any host that I monitor.

so I went to icingaweb2 web interface, and on the left menu I clicked on `Icinga Director` -> `Notifications` and clicked on `Notifications` and then `add`

I actually added two notifications.

for one I imported `mail-host-notification` and for the other `mail-service-notification`.

so host related notifications is one script and service related notifications is a different one.

Since I want to have all kind of notifications to be sent out so in the `Assign where` mandatory thingy i configured for service - `!service.disabled` so as long as it's enabled..and for service I used `host.zone == "master"` since I don't have any satellites so they all are in the same zones.

is it the proper way to go?

I didn't find anywhere to define where to send the email to.

I checked the script and there should be an environment variable (I think) called `USEREMAIL` in order to define where to send this email. I couldn't find where to place it!

so to sum up.. a few questions:

1. are there `Assign where` rules i applied make sense in order to alert all types of notifications from all hosts
2. is this the way to configure email notifications properly ?
3. how do I set required variables like where to send the email to ?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I finally found the solution.

it's at https://monitoring-portal.org/woltlab/index.php?thread/42257-setup-email-notification-through-icinga-director/

in general when I went to `notifications` in directors I didn't notice the menu to create users objects.

so this website show exactly where it is,  I somehow missed it.